# What switching speed limitations will this H-bridge circuit have?

Tags: h-bridge, switching

I would like to use an H-bridge to switch higher voltages (between 5v and 48v using an adjustable linear regulator as the input voltage to the circuit VCC below) on a small piezo electric [buzzer](https://docs.rs-online.com/96a9/0900766b80c6760d.pdf) (reversing polarity on the buzzer). I'm ideally wanting to switch these voltages with really tiny pulses between 1\$\mu\$s and 20\$\mu\$s. I'd like to know if the circuit below would have any limitations to switching small pulses like these on the order of single to tens of microseconds. Is it possible to use this circuit to get close to square output pulses on such tiny width input pulses?

[image: H-bridge circuit]

**edit**

Jonk has suggested simulating this circuit. I can see using a 2N222 transistors that I will not be able to achieve a perfectly square output for such a narrow pulse.The circuit below is using 1K resistor between gate and source and 1k resistors at the base of the transistor.

- I'd like to achieve within 10%-20% tolerance on the width of the amplified pulse between the top of the rising edge and falling edge. For example if my input pulse is 1\$\mu\$s then I'd like my output pulse to remain high at 48V for at least 1.2\$\mu\$s even if the edges of the amplified pulse are not perfectly square. What should I take into consideration to achieve this or is this a poor circuit choice to do this?

Plot 3 and 4 below show the voltage of each output on the bridge.

[image: Simulated]

Comment: Try simulating that circuit. I think you'll see it has problems for the rates you want to achieve.

Comment: A few BJTs can achieve [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vkih6.png). If that's good enough, anyway. That assumed a typical \$\pm 20\:\text{mA}\$ device driven by \$\pm 48\:\text{V}\$.

Comment: @jonk I think for my application it isn't critical if I'm not able to perfectly replicate the input pulse shape, as long as I can get as close as possible with some tolerance.

Comment: Well, you will probably need to show us just what "some tolerance" actually means when discussing \$1\:\mu\text{s}\$ pulse widths. What I showed you was for \$500\:\text{ns}\$ widths -- twice as fast as what you were asking about. It's much sharper at the width you want. My point is just that you should simulate your circuit and see how it fares. I predict "not well." But it's your circuit and you are welcome to it. The BJTs as shown in your schematic are just one part of the problem.

Comment: @jonk I've edited my question to be clearer on what I'd like to achieve. I'm not an experienced circuit designer so I'm looking for advice on better ways to achieve what I'm looking to do.

Comment: With a fairly simple all-BJT topology, nothing terribly fancy, you should be able to achieve about \$80\:\text{ns}\$ rise and fall times into \$100\:\text{pF}\$ or about \$400\:\text{ns}\$ rise and fall times into \$470\:\text{pF}\$. A lot depends on the piezo itself, though. Do you have a good model for it?

Comment: I don't have a good model for it and not much to go off from the datasheet: https://docs.rs-online.com/96a9/0900766b80c6760d.pdf

Comment: Are you planning to run that on \$\pm 5\:\text{V}\$ (to achieve \$10\:\text{V}_\text{PP}\$?) Or the \$48 \:\text{V}\$ you also mentioned? That appears to be about \$22\:\text{nF}\$ load, which will take a lot of current to drive with sharp edges.

Comment: The piezo buzzer is to be used to induce pressure changes in a small chamber with a liquid as part of a single nozzle printhead. I wanted to be able to vary the voltage from +5V to +48V. The pulse width and amplitude parameters need to be tuned to result in single droplet ejection without satellite droplets.

Comment: You may want to find something easier to drive. From the datasheet (\$22\:\text{nF}\$) and from your writing, which may imply \$200\:\text{ns}\$ edges for a \$1\:\mu\text{s}\$ pulse width, that's \$I=22\:\text{nF}\cdot \frac{48\:\text{V} - \left(-48\:\text{V}\right)}{200\:\text{ns}}=10.56\:\text{A}\$ of drive current to the piezo. That's non-trivial to achieve. You'll need to carefully craft this design. Dropping down to a voltage drive that is 10 times lower would mean 10 times less drive current. But it's still non-trivial.

Comment: Your current design uses an active pull-down, but a passive pull-up. You've also got lots of gate capacitance to also drive, let alone the piezo, using those mosfets. Seriously, this will require some care for a discrete design. There may be something in an IC that someone may recommend, though. But you are really looking at a scientific instrument with varying output voltage selection and sharp edges and narrow pulses into significant capacitance. I'd be tempted to look into class-D bridged amplifier ICs, just as a look-see to start. Might find something useful there. Some have to run at MHz.

Comment: I may be confused but would it not be 5.28A? In my simulation I was showing the voltage of output 2 subtracted from the voltage of output 1 so relative to each other there is a 2x48V change. The actual change in voltage should only be from 0 to 48V on either side of the bridge. I've updated the post to show this more clearly. Regardless, 5.28A is still a lot of current and my regulator is only able to supply 3.5A so this is a big design flaw.

Comment: I was imagining a bridged situation with 48 V rails, so 96 V delta in 200 ns. That's about 500 V per microsecond. Times about 20 nF, that's about 10 A. Regardless, a lot of details will matter.

Comment: There's no way that circuit will work at 48V. Expect massive shoot-through currents, and blown Gates due to over-voltage!